# New lvm install to pick up existing home drive and reinstate swap partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, drive, lvm

I've read so many variables on what I'm trying to do, I thought it better to ask outright.

I've been through a few installs and upgrades of Ubuntu but never had my system (root) drive encrypted. Just found out about `lvm` and installed a fresh 12.4 alternate without touching my old and seperate `/home` folder (encrypted I'm sure, although accessible now with root privileges) on another SSD.

I encrypted the (new) `/home` during install. I am looking to combine the two `/home` folders and set up existing swap partition that lies on the old `/home` drive (as I removed the standard swap during install due to a lack of space on the root drive).

Can I do both actions with the `lvm` program?

Comment: I think you're confusing LVM with LUKS and/or EcryptFS. The installer uses LVM with LUKS to do a full disk encryption, and EcryptFS to encrypt the home folder.

Can you post the output of `mount`, `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo pvs` and `sudo lvs` on your computer with the SSD connected and mounted? This will help us determine what your current situation is.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu use eCryptfs to encrypt /home.

The new /home and old home could be using different ciphers, keys and options. I don't think it is possible to merge the 2 logical volumes.

Anyway, you can do it manually by mounting the old home and use rsync to copy all files over to the new /home (data will be encrypted again using the ecryptfs options on the new /home), you can keep using the swap file on the old /home anyway, just edit the `/etc/fstab`

More on eCryptfs
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html